# Changes not staged for commit even after git add

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-commit, git-add

Here are the git commands which I have typed

```
$ git add -u -n
add 'proj1/Foo.scala'
$ git add .
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "message"
On branch feature/branch
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/feature/branch'.
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   ../proj1/Foo.scala
```

So why did I get the `Changes not staged for commit`? as you can see that I did `git add .` twice

Now if I got ahead and do

```
git add ../proj1/Foo.scala
```

and then do commit it works. Why should I do each file specifically rather than just do `git add .`

Comment: I usually do a `git add *` instead ...  Only if you KNOW you want to add ALL the added/changed files in the current working directory .. But usually you know what you want to add to your commit.  And --  You could shorten by committing and adding at the same time using `git commit -a -m "message"` which does the same thing as a `git add *`

Comment: ```git add .``` will only add files in the current directory (aka ```.```). From the path in your copy/pasted commands, it looks like proj1 is up a directory?

Comment: Why does it appear the file has changed location from one command to the next?

When you dry-run the add, it shows the file location as `proj1/Foo.scala`, one directory below the current. Why then does the output later show the location as `../proj1/Foo.scala`?

Comment: @TriskalJM It looks like they're in a subdirectory in the git repo. Since the first one used -u without a path, it looked at the whole repository, so it printed the path relative to the top of the repo. But commit shows paths relative to your current location.

Answer (score 13):

`git add .` by default will add files changed in current working directory and its subdirectories only.

If you want to add all files, use `git add -A` (this works in the latest versions of git).

Alternatively, as pointed by @Zak in comments, you can use `git commit -am "commit message"` to do this in a single step.

Comment: Or he could shorten it by using the "add" flag to the commit --  IE `git commit -a -m "message"`

Comment: git commit - a didnt work for me. but git add -A did the job.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem when `git add <filename>` did not work.
I `cd` down to the directory and did `git add` there and file was added as expected.